# problem for chrome setfocus textbox

Tags: asp.net

ScriptManager scrmgr = (ScriptManager)this.Master.FindControl("scrmgr");
 scrmgr.SetFocus(txtSearch);

this is my coding ,it works all browser.but my problem is chrome display with selection if  textbox has any value..

i want just remove the selection.......

Comment: Why did you make it a community wiki??

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no better solution than code your own setFocus function. The simpliest cross-browser method to remove the selection is to store the text temporarily, clear the value and set it again afterwards. Then call the js-function focus on the input-control.
I think this VB.Net Code helps to get the idea(I dont know if you prefer c#):

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        setFocusOnControl(Me.TextBox1)
    End Sub

    Public Sub setFocusOnControl(ByVal ctrl As Control)
        Dim script As String = "" & vbCrLf & _
            "var control = document.getElementById('" & ctrl.ClientID & "');" & vbCrLf & _
            "var temptext = control.value;" & vbCrLf & _
            "control.value='';" & vbCrLf & _
            "control.value=temptext;" & vbCrLf & _
            "control.focus();" & vbCrLf & _
            "" & vbCrLf

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.Page.GetType, "setFocusOnControlScript", script, True)
    End Sub
```